# ABOUT remote.origin.url

Tags: linux, git, github

I am unable to understand or edit the two conflicting remote.origin.url's in my Codeforces repository for the command "git config --list" .
Someone please help me out what they mean!! And also please tell me how to change them.

I used git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/g1g19/Codeforces.git
But I am not able to change the upper one of the below attached output for "git config --list"

```
$ git config --list   
user.name=g1g19         
user.email=gopichandpaturi@gmail.com   
core.editor=emacs   
merge.tool=vimdiff   
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/g1g19/subsurface.git  
core.repositoryformatversion=0   
core.filemode=true         
core.bare=false     
core.logallrefupdates=true  
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/g1g19/Codeforces.git
```

Answer (score 1):

`git config --list` lists the contents of all relevant config files, that is `/etc/gitconfig` (system-wide), `~/.gitconfig` (user level) and `.git/config` (repo specific). If they contain conflicting entries, the smallest scope wins. Please look through all 3 files. I hope that helps to understand where the duplicate entry is coming from.

As to `remote.origin.url`:

- `remote` is any other repo your repo knows about.
- `remote.origin` is the repo you cloned yours from.
- `remote.origin.url` is its URL.

Comment: What does remote.origin.url actually mean? I don't get it!!               Also how do I change them?Can you please elaborate